# Gitlab and gitlab-runner using docker-in-docker, fails to register new layer ("Failed to create btrfs snapshot: inappropriate ioctl for device")

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, synology, docker-in-docker

I'm having problems running `docker build` from my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file using `docker:dind`, which only strikes when I add new layers.

My gitlab and gitlab-runner are both running as containers in the top-level Docker on my synology NAS (which uses btrfs as a storage driver), as per the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  gitlab:
    container_name: gitlab
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: 'git.MY_FQDN_REDACTED.com'
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: git.MY_FQDN_REDACTED.com
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 80
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://git.MY_FQDN_REDACTED.com'
        nginx['listen_port'] = 80
        nginx['listen_https'] = false
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2222
        registry_external_url 'https://git.MY_FQDN_REDACTED.com:5112'
        registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/certs/MY_FQDN_REDACTED.com.crt"
        registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/certs/MY_FQDN_REDACTED.com.key"
    expose:
      - 80
    ports:
      - "2222:22"
      - "5112:5112"
    networks:
      - default
      - proxy
    volumes:
      - 'gitlab-config:/etc/gitlab'
      - 'gitlab-logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - 'gitlab-data:/var/opt/gitlab'
      - ${SSL_DIR}:/certs
    shm_size: '256m'
  gitlab-build-runner:
    container_name: gitlab-build-runner
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest'
    networks:
      - default
    environment:
      GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "true"
      CA_CERTIFICATES_PATH: "/ca_certs"
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - './gitlab-build-runner/config/config.toml:/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml'
      - '/volume1/docker/ents/ssl/MY_CA_INTERMEDIATE_CERT.pem:/ca_certs/ca.pem'
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  default:
  proxy:
    external: true
    name: proxy

volumes:
  gitlab-logs:
  gitlab-config:
  gitlab-data:
```

The gitlab interface lives behind and is accessed via an nginx reverse proxy (config not shown) and the gitlab container registry is accessed directly (port 5112) and terminates its own TLS. As you can see, gitlab-runner has access to the parent docker socket so runner instances can be spawned at the top level (as in *not* docker-in-docker at this level).

Gitlab-runner config (`/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`) is as follows:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "b66dc462d510"
  url = "http://git.MY_FQDN_REDACTED.com/"
  id = 6
  token = "REDACTED"
  token_obtained_at = 2022-10-10T21:57:00Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/volume1/docker/ents/ssl/MY_CA_INTERMEDIATE_CERT.pem:/ca_certs/ca.pem"]
    shm_size = 0
    pre_build_script = """
    apk update >/dev/null
    apk add ca-certificates > /dev/null
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

    cp /ca_certs/ca.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt
    update-ca-certificates --fresh > /dev/null
    """
```

And I have a basic project with a `Dockerfile`, which uses a `.gitlab-ci.yml` as follows:

```
variables:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "true"

docker-build:
  # Use the official docker image.
  image: docker:dind
  stage: build
  tags:
    - build
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      command: ["--insecure-registry=git.MY_FQDN_REDACTED.com:5112"]
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY

  # Default branch leaves tag empty (= latest tag)
  # All other branches are tagged with the escaped branch name (commit ref slug)
  script:
    - |
      if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" ]]; then
        tag=""
        echo "Running on default branch '$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH': tag = 'latest'"
      else
        tag=":$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
        echo "Running on branch '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH': tag = $tag"
      fi
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}"
  # Run this job in a branch where a Dockerfile exists
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      exists:
        - Dockerfile
```

Now, if my `Dockerfile` is mostly blank, like:

```
FROM debian:stable-slim
```

Then my pipeline works. The image is built, tagged, and pushed to gitlab's container registry, however if I add layers to the `Dockerfile`, as in:

```
FROM debian:stable-slim
RUN apt update -y
```

Then my pipeline fails with `failed to register layer: Failed to create btrfs snapshot: inappropriate ioctl for device`.

Here is the full pipeline output when it fails:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.4.0 (43b2dc3d)
  on b66dc462d510 oPaPyVQX
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:33
Using Docker executor with image docker:dind ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image sha256:c82a93f89b8dca89e129732754f5fe2e948379bd4d28f117036589ab6d039941 for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:5da8f946c2b2b9e37b6554680ef3cac95875cb4f5bf66001c80a5e0cc726ddac ...
Waiting for services to be up and running (timeout 30 seconds)...
Using docker image sha256:c82a93f89b8dca89e129732754f5fe2e948379bd4d28f117036589ab6d039941 for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:5da8f946c2b2b9e37b6554680ef3cac95875cb4f5bf66001c80a5e0cc726ddac ...
Preparing environment
00:06
Running on runner-opapyvqx-project-3-concurrent-0 via f43fcf476734...
Getting source from Git repository
00:05
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/mark/debian-test/.git/
Checking out f49cef34 as main...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:16
Using docker image sha256:c82a93f89b8dca89e129732754f5fe2e948379bd4d28f117036589ab6d039941 for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:5da8f946c2b2b9e37b6554680ef3cac95875cb4f5bf66001c80a5e0cc726ddac ...
$ docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
$ if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" ]]; then # collapsed multi-line command
Running on default branch 'main': tag = 'latest'
$ docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}" .
Step 1/2 : FROM debian:stable-slim
stable-slim: Pulling from library/debian
5c556efcf56e: Pulling fs layer
5c556efcf56e: Download complete
5c556efcf56e: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:92ed72016796475ea1f18f84cd8e2f8519ece3a9ea27fdde1157464078ea5371
Status: Downloaded newer image for debian:stable-slim
 ---> 6a53e0f5c32d
Step 2/2 : RUN apt update -y
Failed to create btrfs snapshot: inappropriate ioctl for device
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Any ideas how I overcome this? I've tried setting btrfs storage driver in the CI job variables, but that doesn't work. What am I missing?

EDIT: One other thing I've just tried, was to match the docker versions through the stack, with a view to also matching the Btrfs versions, so... In gitlab-runner `config.toml`:

```
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:20.10.3"
```

and in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
docker-build:
  image: docker:20.10.3-dind
  stage: build
  services:
    - name: docker:20.10.3-dind
```

And now the docker versions between top-level host (nas), gitlab-runner instance and build container all match 20.10.3, but there is still a mismatch of Btrfs versions...

top-level host (nas):

```
 Server Version: 20.10.3
 Storage Driver: btrfs
  Build Version: Btrfs v4.0
  Library Version: 101
 Logging Driver: json-file
```

docker:dind build container:

```
 Server Version: 20.10.3
 Storage Driver: btrfs
  Build Version: Btrfs v4.20.1 
  Library Version: 102
 Logging Driver: json-file
```

Not sure what else to try. I definitely don't want to change anything about the btrfs implementation of the synology nas.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've managed to make this work, first by regressing the version of docker I use in my build container to attempt to match the Btrfs Storage Driver Library Version (to 101). So .gitlab-ci.yml with:

```
docker-build:
  image: docker:17.03.1-dind
  stage: build
  services:
    - name: docker:17.03.1-dind
```

And the container builds the extra layers as it should, but `docker info` inside the build container shows that the storage driver being used is defaulting to `vfs`:

```
Server Version: 17.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: vfs
```

I then switched the version back to 20.10.3 and forced vfs storage driver:

```
variables:
[SNIP]
  DOCKER_DRIVER: vfs

docker-build:
  image: docker:20.10.3-dind
  stage: build
  services:
    - name: docker:20.10.3-dind
```

And this now works. afaik `vfs` driver isn't ideal, but this/my use-case, performance isn't an issue.